# Can I inject a content script automatically in manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm making a browser extension that injects a stylesheet into a specific website, but in migrating to mv3 I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm not sure what permissions I need to allow it. Currently if I click on the toolbar icon it will then load the sylesheet, I just want to know how to do it automatically on page load.

This is my manifest.json

```
{

  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "inject dark theme",
  "version": "1.2",

  "description": "Finally a worthy dark theme!",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [website is here but I can't say what is it],
      "css": ["style.css"]
    }
  ]
  
}
```

Comment: There's no need for any permissions. The behavior you described (theme applied after clicking) is impossible with the code you've shown, which means it's a bug in Chrome or your actual extension is different or you've explicitly overridden its access permissions inside chrome://extensions UI or in the context menu by mistake. Try uninstalling the extension and reinstall it again to clear the internal state. Also add "run_at":"document_start" to apply the theme earlier.